# Why does my maven break into closed repository?

Tags: maven, repository

I have configured many repositories, as I found in

```
MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml
```

I was thinking this will increase availability of packages for my workplace.

Unfortunately it creates some additional problems. For example, I have configured repository

```
                <repository>
                    <id>lhogie.i3s.maven.repo</id>
                    <name>Luc Hogie Maven repository</name>
                    <url>http://www.i3s.unice.fr/~hogie/maven_repository/</url>
                </repository>
```

which website is currently down or is unstable.

Nevertheless, my Maven is trying to download something from this repository again and again, receiving permission denied and then trying again. It does this even for those packages, which are calmly present on central repository.

Why?

Why doesn't it try other repositories if knocked out of one of them?

**SAMPLE OF STDOUT**

```
Downloading: http://www.i3s.unice.fr/~hogie/maven_repository/org/eclipse/jetty/toolchain/jetty-toolchain/1.4/jetty-toolchain-1.4.pom
ш■э 25, 2014 4:18:22 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Permission denied: connect
ш■э 25, 2014 4:18:22 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
ш■э 25, 2014 4:18:43 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Permission denied: connect
ш■э 25, 2014 4:18:43 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
ш■э 25, 2014 4:19:04 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Permission denied: connect
ш■э 25, 2014 4:19:04 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because Maven doesn't want to hide problems from you. I don't know the algorithm which Maven uses but I think it just tries all repos in order until it finds what it looks for. So you can simply add Maven Central as the first repo and it will stop early.

But a better solution is usually to install a proxy server in your local network. It will keep a mirror of all the packages that you use. You can then tell Maven to ask the proxy (so you don't have to keep N repos in the same state in all `settings.xml` of many developers) plus doing the first build for a new developer (or for you when you have to wipe your local repo) will be much faster.

Comment: Maven could show me an error, but why it is trying to access which is inaccessible again and again?

Comment: Maven has error handling for repos which don't contain a certain version of an artifact or which don't contain an artifact at all but what would be a good handling for a repo which you can access right now? That's now something where you can say what the "correct" handling would be in every case (plus there is no way to tell which errors mean "repo isn't accessible")